# Unable to use SIFT Features in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I've been trying to solve a certain template matching problem for which I plan to use SIFT features. I went through various blogs and stack overflow questions (most of them old) and understood that SIFT is not supported any more for it's patented. I even tried installing the exact package versions which they suggested. I don't know why I'm unable to get it to work still.
Following is my package list

```
astroid==2.2.5
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
idna==2.8
imutils==0.5.3
isort==4.3.21
kiwisolver==1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.2
matplotlib==3.1.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.18.1
opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
opencv-python==3.4.2.16
pylint==2.3.1
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
six==1.13.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.7
wrapt==1.11.2
```

and the python version is 3.6.8 
I want to know if there's still a certain combination of archived packages so that I can work with SIFT features. Otherwise, are there any alternatives to SIFT features

Comment: Have you used CMAKE with and set the OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE flag to true?

Comment: No, I haven't. Can you please elaborate? Also, it sounds like a C++ related suggestion and I need to use it in python

Comment: It's actually an installation suggestion. You have to rebuild opencv with the OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE if you insist on using SIFT. Can't help you much more than that, I'm using ORB instead of SIFT